# Formatting a complete project in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

To format a file in the editor, you press Alt+Shift+F. Is there a way for formatting the complete project(s) in NetBeans (6.8, if that makes any difference)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mass formatting is supported since NetBeans 7.2. See

- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/mass_format_in_netbeans_ide
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeU_KZC5lI0

Answer (score 27):

Select the folder you want to indent.

Then, go (in netbeans menu) to source / format

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Select project or subfolder node in **Projects** window and press *Alt+Shift+F*.